# Dialogflow integration with BigQuery - Passing integer parameters to BQ

Tags: google-bigquery, dialogflow-es

I'm creating a chatbot that retrieves data from BigQuery but I'm having issues with the data types in Dialogflow:

Dialogflow parameters are: Rating (@sys.number-int), Country (string), Department (String)

When I execute the following code, it seems bigquery is receiving the Rating as a string (Country and Department which are strings are working fine in BigQuery), so that's why I've tried CAST but no luck.

Can someone help me to pass INT64 variables to BigQuery from Dialogflow?

```
 function buyAgainPredictor(agent) {
    const OPTIONS = {
                query: 'WITH pred_table AS (SELECT CAST(`request.body.queryResult.outputContexts[0].parameters.Rating´ AS INT64) as Rating, "request.body.queryResult.outputContexts[0].parameters.Department" as Department,  "request.body.queryResult.outputContexts[0].parameters.Country" as Country)' +
                'SELECT cast(predicted_label as INT64) as predicted_label ' +
                'FROM ML.PREDICT(MODEL Customer_feedback.recommend_model,  TABLE pred_table)',
                timeoutMs: 10000,
                useLegacySql: false,
                queryParameters: {}
```

[DialogFlow parameter definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umkdx.png)

Comment: Why do you think it receives it as a string?

Answer (score 0):

You are not replacing the variables within the string. Try this in `query`:

```js
`WITH pred_table AS (
  SELECT ${request.body.queryResult.outputContexts[0].parameters.Rating} as Rating,
     "${request.body.queryResult.outputContexts[0].parameters.Department}" as Department,
     "${request.body.queryResult.outputContexts[0].parameters.Country}" as Country)

SELECT cast(predicted_label as INT64) as predicted_label 
     FROM ML.PREDICT(MODEL Customer_feedback.recommend_model, TABLE pred_table)`
```

Normally, you wouldn't want to use user input in your SQL queries ([SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)), check the documentation on [parameterized queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#running_parameterized_queries). Taking that into consideration, you could try this:

```js
const OPTIONS = {
    query: `WITH pred_table AS (
                SELECT @rating as Rating,
                       @department as Department,  
                       @country as Country)

            SELECT cast(predicted_label as INT64) as predicted_label
                 FROM ML.PREDICT(MODEL Customer_feedback.recommend_model, TABLE pred_table)`,

    timeoutMs: 10000,
    useLegacySql: false,
    queryParameters: {
        rating: parameters.Rating,
        department: parameters.Department,
        country: parameters.Country
    }
}
```